# Mysql Select With nested If and count

Tags: php, mysql

need help with my code please sorry I just post short raw of my query here is the full one

```
SELECT si_visit.company, IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Regular',1, NULL)),COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Regular',1, NULL))) 'Regular',
IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Installation',4, NULL)),COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Installation',1, NULL))) 'Installation', 
IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Emergency',4, NULL)),COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Emergency',1, NULL))) 'Emergency', 
IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Cancellation',1, NULL)),COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Cancellation',1, NULL))) 'Cancellation', 
IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Remotely',1, NULL)),COUNT(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Remotely',1, NULL))) 'Remotely', 
COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM si_visit INNER JOIN si_visit_type WHERE si_visit_type.visit_name= si_visit.visit_type  
GROUP BY si_visit.company
```

what i need is to count the Emergency, Installation as 4 if the company name is SIPES other count it as 1
and the php code is

```
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
$statement = $connection->prepare($query . $query1);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
foreach($result as $row){
$sub_array = array();
//$sub_array[] = $nub;
$sub_array[] = $row["company"];
$sub_array[] = $row["Regular"];
$sub_array[] = $row["Emergency"];
$sub_array[] = $row["Remotely"];
$sub_array[] = $row["Installation"];
$sub_array[] = $row["Cancellation"];
$sub_array[] = $row["Total"];
$data[] = $sub_array;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

and my database tables is :

```
CREATE TABLE `si_visit` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`visit_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`engineer_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`notes` text NOT NULL,
`visit_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Visits table for Clients';

CREATE TABLE `si_visit_type` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`visit_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`visit_count` int(11) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Visit type and count for it';
INSERT INTO `si_visit_type` (`id`, `visit_name`, `visit_count`) VALUES
(1, 'Regular', 1),
(2, 'Installation', 4),
(3, 'Emergency', 4),
(4, 'Cancellation', 1),
(5, 'Remotely', 1);
```

when i query it it count all as 1 i try it a lot of method all gives me error
using mysql with MariaDB

what i do wrong?? 
Please if u can help

Comment: This is not a PHP question, as is. If PHP is relevant please add the code. What happens when you execute this query? Can you add sample data, or create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: when i put it my php file to get a function with row count and display the data to the client side

Comment: Remove the PHP tag as this is a MYSQL question.

Comment: Is the issue with the PHP implementation or just executing the query? Sample data would be useful. Also breaking down each condition to its own line would make the query more readable.

Comment: We need to see some sample data and your database structure so we can test it in something like sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, 
I just figured out i used count and that is count the row
I just change it to sum and it come out right
Thank you everyone.

```
  SELECT si_visit.company,
 IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Regular',1, 0)),SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Regular',1, 0))) 'Regular',
IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Installation',4, 0)),SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Installation',1, 0))) 'Installation',
IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Emergency',4, 0)),SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Emergency',1, 0))) 'Emergency',
IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Cancellation',1, 0)),SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Cancellation',1, 0))) 'Cancellation',
IF(si_visit.company='SIPES',SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Remotely',1, 0)),SUM(IF(si_visit.visit_type='Remotely',1, 0))) 'Remotely', COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM si_visit INNER JOIN si_visit_type WHERE si_visit_type.visit_name= si_visit.visit_type GROUP BY si_visit.company
```